# Flutter: Is it safe to use ValueNotifier with class static variables?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to find a simple and clean way to manage my state in Flutter without using third party libraries. I chose to use `ValueNotifier` in combination with `ValueListenableBuilder` in order to be selective about what's being rebuilt in my app when changes occurs.

I've created a class to expose my state values using static variables so they can be used and get directly updated from anywhere without having to do any complicated gymnastic. I'm not sure it is a good practice (it looks to easy in comparison to other state management solutions) but it works.

Could you tell me why this potentially wouldn't be a viable solution?

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final CounterState _counterState = CounterState();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final count = _counterState.counter;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            ValueListenableBuilder(
                valueListenable: _counterState.counter,
                builder: (BuildContext context, int count, _) => Text(
                      'parent count: $count',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                    )),
            const ChildWidget()
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => count.value++,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}

class ChildWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChildWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ChildWidget> createState() => _ChildWidgetState();
}

class _ChildWidgetState extends State<ChildWidget> {
  final CounterState _counterState = CounterState();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: _counterState.counter,
      builder: (BuildContext context, int count, _) => Center(
        child: Text(
          'child count: $count',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CounterState {
  static final ValueNotifier<int> _counter = ValueNotifier<int>(0);

  ValueNotifier<int> get counter => _counter;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is the recommended way. Either declare (and dispose) `ValueNotifier` in the state class where you use it, or if you have to manage state throughout the widget tree, then use `ChangeNotifier`, `Consumer`, `Provider` etc.